# alsa-utils on FreeBSD don't seem to work

Tags: freebsd, alsa, i3

I have working sound. I can play a youtube video through chrome and sound works just fine.  However, I'm using i3 as my window manager and I am trying to setup the fn+sound keys to raise and lower the volume.  I've found a command using the alsa-utils to do that:

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 2%+ unmute
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 2%- unmute
```

However that doesn't seem to work.  When I run the amixer command from a shell I get the following error:

```
ALSA lib control.c:1352:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL pulse
amixer: Mixer attach pulse error: No such file or directory
```

Digging into this further I tried:

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:273: no soundcards found...
```

However as I said, I have working sound.  FreeBSD seems to be aware of my sound card:

```
$ cat /dev/sndstat
Installed devices:
pcm0: <NVIDIA (0x0044) (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
pcm1: <NVIDIA (0x0044) (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
pcm2: <NVIDIA (0x0044) (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
pcm3: <NVIDIA (0x0044) (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
pcm4: <Realtek ALC892 (Rear Analog 7.1/2.0)> (play/rec) default
pcm5: <Realtek ALC892 (Front Analog)> (play/rec)
pcm6: <Realtek ALC892 (Rear Digital)> (play)
pcm7: <Realtek ALC892 (Onboard Digital)> (play)
pcm8: <USB audio> (rec)
pcm9: <USB audio> (rec)
No devices installed from userspace.
```

Any idea whats going on with the alsa mixer or is there another way I can setup the fn+sound keys?

Comment: Honest question: Does FreeBSD actually use ALSA?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure...I installed it using `pkg install alsa-utils` so maybe I incorrectly just assumed that it would work.

Comment: `alsa-utils` is just client software. It has nothing to do with OS support for the Advanced Linux Sound Architecture.

Comment: Right...I just didn't think they would include the utilities in the package manager if there were no support for it, but I don't know how it all works to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I searched for an alternative method to accomplish mapping my media keys and learned that the `mixer` command will do what I want and works just fine.  Here is what I ended up with:

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec mixer vol +2
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec mixer vol -2
```